# Overlapping objects still show object underneath in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am having issues with objects overlapping.

If I create a red rectangle in Illustrator, then copy it, and paste it directly on top of itself and change it to white, I get a red outline, even though the object is supposed to cover the other object behind.

Why is that? It's driving me nuts, please someone help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you see the red outline because the zoom level in relation to the shapes sizes doesn't match up, and therefore you get a "ghost boarder" of the underlying shape. If you press Command + 1 (Ctrl + 1 on Windows) which zooms you to actual size of the document then the boarder should not be visible (As long as the shapes you have are of the EXACT same size).